# My col-xs-12 is ruining my row in tablet and desktop mode

Tags: html, css

```css
.col-xs-15,
.col-sm-15,
.col-md-15,
.col-lg-15 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.col-md-15 img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.margin20
{
 margin-top: 20px;
}
/*new set of column*/
.col-xs-15 {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 /*even if i remove this nothing happen*/
.col-sm-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
*overlay*/
.img-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.red {
  background-color: #B2B2B2; 
}
.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.img-container .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.img-container .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Custom.css" type="text/css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet"> 
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Black" rel="stylesheet"> 
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-15 col-xs-12">
     <div class="img-container red">
       <img src="https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/mandrill200x200.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
       <div class="middle">
         <div class="text">MEN'S APPAREL</div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-15 col-xs-12">
     <div class="img-container red">
       <img src="https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/mandrill200x200.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
       <div class="middle">
         <div class="text">MEN'S APPAREL</div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-15 col-xs-12">
     <div class="img-container red">
       <img src="img/sample.png" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
       <div class="middle">
         <div class="text">MEN'S APPAREL</div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-15 col-xs-12">
     <div class="img-container red">
       <img src="https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/mandrill200x200.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
       <div class="middle">
         <div class="text">MEN'S APPAREL</div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-15 col-xs-12">
     <div class="img-container red">
       <img src="https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/mandrill200x200.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
       <div class="middle">
         <div class="text">MEN'S APPAREL</div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row margin20">
    <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-15 col-xs-12">
     <div class="img-container red">
       <img src="https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/mandrill200x200.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
       <div class="middle">
         <div class="text">MEN'S APPAREL</div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-15 col-xs-12">
     <div class="img-container red">
       <img src="https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/mandrill200x200.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
       <div class="middle">
         <div class="text">MEN'S APPAREL</div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-15 col-xs-12">
     <div class="img-container red">
       <img src="https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/mandrill200x200.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
       <div class="middle">
         <div class="text">MEN'S APPAREL</div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-15 col-xs-12">
     <div class="img-container red">
       <img src="https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/mandrill200x200.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
       <div class="middle">
         <div class="text">MEN'S APPAREL</div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-15 col-xs-12">
     <div class="img-container red">
       <img src="https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/mandrill200x200.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
       <div class="middle">
         <div class="text">MEN'S APPAREL</div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

I want to divide my row in 5 equal parts that is why i used col-md-15 and col-sm-15, it is working well in tablet,mobile,and desktop (if you will remove the col-xs-12 in every tag), however in mobile mode i want the images to be 1 per row that is why i inserted col-xs-12, however when i did that, the rows in tablet and desktop mode became 1 per row and stretched which is i dont want. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Its because you have not added any custom style for col-xs-12. Try defining the media property for col-xs-12 and it will work fine.

Comment: i tried that like this: @media (min-width: 768px) {

 .col-xs-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
but nothing happen

Comment: replace min-width with max-width

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Custom.css" type="text/css"/>
```

You load custom css before bootstrap css, switch that around.

Edited the example, sry, I meant the other way around. Custom css last, so it overrides the other code.

Comment: it is loaded like that